# Mostrar solo una tabla de un dataset c#

Tags: c#, webservice, webforms

Buenas tardes estimados, 
Estoy trabajando en webform donde tengo un webservices con un método que se llama obtenerRecorrido, este metodo me devuelve un dataset compuesto de varias tablas:

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence><xs:element name="codigo_recorrido" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="fecha" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="hora" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="comentario" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="resolucion" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="cargo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="descarea" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="documentos" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="fecha_fin_gestion" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram>
<NewDataSet>
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<codigo_recorrido>-1</codigo_recorrido>
<fecha>2019-03-25T15:49:33.23-03:00</fecha>
<hora>2019-03-25T15:49:33.23-03:00</hora>
<resolucion>false</resolucion>
<nombre>Nombre1</nombre>
<cargo>No registra Cargo</cargo>
<descarea>No area</descarea>
<documentos>false</documentos>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<codigo_recorrido>5630267</codigo_recorrido>
<fecha>2019-03-25T15:49:36.543-03:00</fecha>
<hora>2019-03-25T15:49:36.543-03:00</hora>
<resolucion>false</resolucion>
<nombre>Nombre2</nombre>
<cargo>No registra Cargo</cargo>
<descarea>No area</descarea>
<documentos>false</documentos>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<codigo_recorrido>5630268</codigo_recorrido>
<fecha>2019-03-25T15:51:05.67-03:00</fecha>
<hora>2019-03-25T15:51:05.67-03:00</hora>
<resolucion>false</resolucion>
<nombre>Nombre3</nombre>
<cargo>No registra cargo</cargo>
<descarea>No area</descarea>
<documentos>false</documentos>
<fecha_fin_gestion>2019-03-25T15:53:34.16-03:00</fecha_fin_gestion>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Este servicio lo consumi como referencia web y he llamado otros métodos y todo bien, mi duda surge en cómo puedo mostrar los datos de las tablas en una sola tabla, cabe recalcar que estoy trabajando en un proyecto web.
De antemano muchas gracias.
Para llamarlo hago esto

```
var servicio = new wsCorrespondencia();
            DataSet ds = servicio.ObtenerRecorridoCopiaCorrespondencia(1, Session["@Codigo-Registro@"].ToString(), Session["@Contrasena@"].ToString());
            grdRecorridoExterna.DataSource = ds;
            grdRecorridoExterna.DataBind();
```

Donde en se muestra aquí, pero se muestran todas las tablas

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdRecorridoExterna" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped" EnableViewState="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha" DataField="fecha" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="descarea" HeaderText="Área" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="cargo" HeaderText="Cargo" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Que forma horrible de devolver los datos tiene ese servicio, devuelve un registro en cada datatable, es un diseño pesimo. No puede contactar quien realizo ese servicio y que retorne las rows en un unico datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias ver si `linq` te permite convertir los datos

Para eso primero defina la clase

```
public class RecorridoCorrespondencia{
    public DateTime fecha {get;set;}
    public string nombre {get;set;}
    public string descarea {get;set;}
    public string cargo {get;set;}
}
```

y luego convertes los `datatable` a la clase para aplanar los datos

```
var result = from dt in ds.Tables
              from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             select new RecorridoCorrespondencia()
             {
                fecha = row.Field<DateTime>("fecha"),
                nombre = row.Field<string>("nombre"),
                descarea = row.Field<string>("descarea"),
                cargo = row.Field<string>("cargo")
              };

grdRecorridoExterna.DataSource = result.ToList();
grdRecorridoExterna.DataBind();
```